# ZF2/composer: detect PHP 5.6

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, php-5.6

I'm creating a project that is using Zend Framework 2 as the framework.

In my composer.json I've got the following line:

```
"zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
```

When I execute composer install, I've got the following error:

```
- zendframework/zendframework 2.3.1 requires php >=5.3.23 -> no matching package found.
```

But...  I've got PHP 5.6 on my system.
I know that it still is not stable yet, but by the time that the application will be released, we expect that PHP 5.6 will be released as stable, so nothing to worry about for now.
I've think that composer is unable to detect this PHP version just because it's not yet stable, but am not sure about it.

Somebody with an idea?

Comment: I would be surprised if that was the issue. Does `php -v` show the correct version number?

Comment: Yes, it does. It shows that I'm using php 5.6 RC2. Can't show it now, because i'm on another pc right now, but tomorrow I can even post a literally copy paste.

Comment: please check if you are in windows if your ``PATH`` system variable  and php path points to your correct php folder. i had the same issue with multiple php versions and an old entry was pointing to an older version of php

Comment: Only have 1 php version installed at the moment. My PATH points to the correct version.
This is the output of php -v:
PHP 5.6.0RC2 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2014 12:38:54)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

Comment: what does `composer show -p | grep php` give you?

Comment: php                 5.6.0RC2 The PHP interpreter. That version is higher then 5.3.23, or does composer think otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is/was unable to determine unstable PHP packages.

A solution for my problem is:

```
php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to put the version of php, try:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.*",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*"
}
```

And run:

```
php composer.phar self-update

php composer.phar install
```